# Creating log in system using php and LDAP

Tags: php

I've been scouring the internet to make a log in using LDAP.

So far I've got some code but as soon as I hit submit nothing seems to be happening, I don't know if i'm missing something so painfully obvious or i've coded it wrong but I would appreciate any help you can give.

Code in question:
index.html

```
<?php
include("authenticate.php");
// check to see if user is logging out
if(isset($_GET['out'])) {
    // destroy session
    session_unset();
    $_SESSION = array();
    unset($_SESSION['user'],$_SESSION['access']);
    session_destroy();
}

// check to see if login form has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['userLogin'])){
    // run information through authenticator
    if(authenticate($_POST['userLogin'],$_POST['userPassword']))
    {
        header("Location: https://hyperspice.net/protected.php", true, 301);
        die();
    } else {
        // authentication failed
        $error = 1;
    }
}


// output error to user
if(isset($error))echo "Login failed: Incorrect user name, password, or rights";

// output logout success
if(isset($_GET['out'])) echo "Logout successful";
?>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hyperspice</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">

  <link rel="logo" type="image/png" href="images/logo.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="one-half column" style="margin-top: 25%">
        <form method="post" action="index.html">
  <div class="imgcontainer">
   <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Hyperslice Ltd" />
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <label for="userLogin"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="userLogin" required>

    <label for="userPassword"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="userPassword" required>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" ></input>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>

</form> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

authenticate.php: 
I changed the variable contents to something different for security

```
<?php
function authenticate($user, $password){

    if(empty($user) || empty($password)) return false;

    $ldap_host = "1234.net";

    $ldap_dn = "OU=departments,DC=1234,DC=net";

    $ldap_user_group = "users";

    $ldap_manager_group = "managers";

    $ldap_usr_dom = "@1234.net";

    $ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_host);

    ldap_set_option($ldap,LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);
    ldap_set_option($ldap,LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0);

    // verify user and password
    if($bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $user.$ldap_usr_dom, $password)) {
        // valid
        // check presence in groups
        $filter = "(sAMAccountName=".$user.")";
        $attr = array("memberof");
        $result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attr) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
        $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
        ldap_unbind($ldap);

        // check groups
        $access = 0;
        foreach($entries[0]['memberof'] as $grps) {
            // is manager, break loop
            if(strpos($grps, $ldap_manager_group)) { $access = 2; break; }

            // is user
            if(strpos($grps, $ldap_user_group)) $access = 1;
        }

        if($access != 0) {
            // establish session variables
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['access'] = $access;
            return true;
        } else {
            // user has no rights
            return false;
        }

    } else {
        // invalid name or password
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

protected.php:

```
<?php
// initialize session
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    // user is not logged in, do something like redirect to login.php
    header("Location: index.html");
    die();
}

if($_SESSION['access'] != 2) {
    // another example...
    // user is logged in but not a manager, let's stop him
    die("Access Denied");
}
?>

<p>Welcome <?= $_SESSION['user'] ?>!</p>

<p><strong>Secret Protected Content Here!</strong></p>

<p>Mary Had a Little Lamb</p>

<p><a href="index.html?out=1">Logout</a></p>
```

I have a feeling it's something to do with the header in index.html or that the form is not posting the contents of the form correctly to authenticate.php.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: If it blanks out, you have to check web server logs. I'd say that you probably don't have LDAP extension installed, but it's just guessing. Also, you're using `sAMAccountName`, that's what AD uses. Two questions pop out: first is - why would you trouble yourself with LDAP for authentication, and two - is it OpenLDAP / FreeIPA or ActiveDirectory used?

Comment: There's no error checking in your code. A liberal sprinkling of ldap_error() and logging is advisable.

Comment: It's active directory that we're using and i've just been told to use LDAP by my management leaders. I am quite a bit of a novice with php and haven't used it for a couple of years so it's a bit rusty for me.

Comment: Well... do you define your request anywhere? Like before method call of `authentication($username, $password)` set the variables like `$username = $_POST['username']; $password = $_POST['password']`. And please check if `memberof` is returning all groups as one single string. consider exploding the string and setting up an array after that.

Comment: I've got LDAP extension installed on the CentOS machine i'm using and i've declared the variables as mentioned but it still hasn't worked. I think the form is sending something because the form clears itself and the page refreshes. How would I be able to check if memberof is returning them all as a string? Again, i'm not very good at php, it's just a little project my work wanted me to get on with to learn more about the language

Comment: You are posting to `index.html`. Is your web server set up to even parse `.html` as `.php` files? If the answer is "i don't know" or "no" - there's your mistake. No PHP gets executed, ever. Also, while it's commendable that you're dabbling with PHP, please bear in mind that even though you can code like you are doing now - it's not recommended to do it like that, as that's quite a bit of cabbage code going on. It's great for testing and fiddling, but from experience - that kind of crap ends up in production and hipster army bashes the language for being "bad".

Comment: Thanks for the advice N.B. I changed it to a php file and the script is running now. I've put some echo statements in the index.php file. If I place an echo command on line 15 it displays but if I place it on line 16 nothing displays. This suggests to me that the header is not working correctly. I am getting the error "Login Failed: Incorrect user name, password or right" even though I know for a fact that the details are correct.

Answer (score 0):

> if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
> // user is not logged in, do something like redirect to login.php
> header("Location: index.html");
> die(); }

the session 'blank' and back to Location

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.